# Azure Key Vault VM Extension for Windows marks private key as unexportable

Tags: windows, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-vm

I am using the [Azure Key Vault VM Extension for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/key-vault-windows) to sync a certificate from my Key Vault to the LocalMachine certificate store.

```
2021-12-08 19:33:20: <info> [CertificateManager]    retrieved 'https://<key vault URL>/secrets/<certificate name>/'; most recent version is 'https://<key vault URL>/secrets/<certificate name>/4e511fa20d7e440ea05bbac1bda915ed'; the ContentType is 'application/x-pkcs12'
2021-12-08 19:33:20: <info> [CertificateManager]    Installing latest version of 'https://<key vault URL>/secrets/<certificate name>/'.
2021-12-08 19:33:20: <debug> [WindowsCertificateStore]  installing certificate..
2021-12-08 19:33:20: <debug> [WindowsCertificateStore]  finding predecessors for model certificate by SAN..
2021-12-08 19:33:20: <info> [WindowsCertificateStore]   Importing the Intermediate CA: R3 
2021-12-08 19:33:20: <debug> [WindowsCertificateStore]  certificate installed
2021-12-08 19:33:20: <info> [CertificateManager]    Completed refreshing observed certificates.
2021-12-08 19:33:20: <info> [CertificateManager]    Successfully started Key Vault extension service. 2021-12-09T00:33:20Z
```

I can see the certificate in the store, and see that its private key is available.

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will export the certificate to a PFX file so I can import it into a third-party application running on the server. The problem is, when I try to export the certificate, I get this error.

```
PS> Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\MY\5A25F9C8319B54336ED245524FF02974C54333CB | Export-PfxCertificate -Password $password -FilePath C:\Users\cwoodcox\Downloads\staging.pfx
Export-PfxCertificate : Cannot export non-exportable private key.
At line:1 char:86
```

If I download the certificate manually with the `az` CLI, the private key is exportable, so it is not the certificate setting the policy. I believe this is because when the extension imports the certificate, it sets the policy to not allow the private key to be exported. I cannot find any documented way to configure the extension to set the policy differently.

I can script downloading the certificate manually via `az`, but then I don't get the `"observedCertificates"` functionality where it checks and imports automatically, which would be awesome. I had planned to use [New-CertificateNotificationTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-certificatenotificationtask?view=windowsserver2019-ps) to react to the cert being updated and export it to a file, and consume the file in the third-party app.

Is there a secret configuration option to set this in the extension? Can the extension be modified to add one? I'm open to other suggestions too.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design because of security implications on the VM. As you've already determined, if you need the private key you should instead script `az` to determine and download the private key accordingly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "security implications on the VM"? It seems like this could at least be configurable, or the rationale could be discussed in the documentation.

Comment: Those details weren't shared with me from the owning team, but I imagine it's to prevent leaking the private key when the certificate can be downloaded easily through the extensions. Workarounds are available, as you've noted, but then becomes very clear in intent from the user.

Comment: If this could _at least_ be discussed in the documentation as a caveat, that would be amazing. I would still love to hear more about the rationale too, or why there's not an option that would enable export when it's installed on the machine. We spent so long trying to figure out what we were doing wrong when generating the certificate (since exportability of private key is typically set then) and it was never our fault and there was nothing we could do!